# JPA StackOverflowError with recursive relationship

Tags: jpa, recursion, eclipselink, stack-overflow, entity-relationship

I am using Eclipselink to persist the following Entities (insignificant code left out):

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="testEntity")
    private List<OtherTestEntity> other = new ArrayList<OtherTestEntity>();
}

@Entity
@IdClass(OtherTestEntityPK.class)
public class OtherTestEntity {
    public static class OtherTestEntityPK {
        public int testEntity;
        public int id;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private TestEntity testEntity;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private OtherTestEntity parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<OtherTestEntity> childs = new ArrayList<OtherTestEntity>();
}
```

While trying to persist a TestEntity, I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [anaflow] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.sap.anaflow.analysis.model.persistence.PersistenceManager.persist(PersistenceManager.java:17)
    at com.sap.anaflow.analysis.model.persistence.PersistenceTest.testPersistence(PersistenceTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [anaflow] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:239)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.getMappingsByField(ObjectBuilder.java:3508)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.getMappingForField(ObjectBuilder.java:3486)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:894)
----- Many, many more of these -----
```

Apart from that Error, I would like to know how to define a constraint that the childs and parents of one OtherTestEntity have the same TestEntity, so that the Database only needs to save a single id-mapping without the foreign key.
This is necessary because my real project contains a composite of 5 foreign keys.

Comment: I didn't know that an `@ID` can be `@ManyToOne`? From my point of view this violates the contract that an ID is always unique for every instance.

Comment: As far as I understood it, this is ok since the Id is a composite.
At least it works in my other classes.
If this is a bad Idea, let me know, since I am new to JPA.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't look at the second `@Id`. What is your version of Eclipse-Link? Did you check https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405635 ?

Comment: Ah, thank you, that seems to be it. I am using Eclipse-Link 2.6.1-RC1.